# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I have this code:

```
try {
   insertRowInDatabase();
} catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
  //row already inserted. Do nothing.
} catch(Exception other) {
  //we should retry to insert row
  retry();  
}
```

Is it possible, that insert of row into oracle database throws SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, but that row will be absent in database after all.

Comment: I have a single table with primary key constraint. No triggers or foreign keys exists.

Comment: My question is more about consistency and isolation level, that Oracle database provide by default. Not about triggers and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Sure. What if there’s a foreign key constraint, or a custom trigger on the table that would prevent the insert? Without the schema it’s hard to tell.

Comment: Sorry. I have to think about schema in my question.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you need PL/SQL's `MERGE`, it's similar like mysql's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`

you can see `MERGE` example [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2516492)

Comment: Merge is not atomic operation for oracle. So constraint violation exception still posible